# How to set up QA and UAT environment in SharePoint ONLINE(not on-prem) for SPFx solutions

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I've tried to search on the internet for quite a while but still can't find a concrete answer to this question.
For DEV and QA environment, SP recommends to create a tenant for each developer, I am not sure about this, but this seems to be expensive, is there any other alternatives?
For UAT environment, I do have read some articles saying that create a dedicate tenant for UAT testing, again, this seems more expensive as there might be quite a lot of users(licenses) to be created in this tenant.
Is it possible to create a site collection for DEV, QA and UAT respectively under the same tenant? Can this approach simulate all the app/webpart deployment, update, etc.?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always create separate site collection for Dev, QA and UAT. For SPFx solution you can deploy the solution at site collection level till QA and UAT level. With this approach:

- Dev site collection can be used by all the developers.
- Separate QA and UAT site collectiosn and SPFx deployed at QA/UAT site collection level can be used by all the QA/UAT members.
- If SPFx solution is created for specific user then one site collection can be created as production site collection and SPFx solution can be deployed at site collection level or at tenant level.

Comment: Thanks Harminder! Our problem now is that we've already got a lot of teamsites at the tenant root level, they are all flat, e.g. ourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/a, sites/b, sites/c...., if we were creating QA and UAT environments, it would be something like /sites/qa/a, /sites/uat/a, etc. As you can see here the QA and UAT environment won't be able to simulate the Production environment 'cause they are actually one level deeper than production, especially for tenant level apps(especially for upgrading an existing app). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what you want to achieve with the DEV site collection. If everything you are testing is only on an site level then that should be the best approach.

But for example, if you are creating a component library or a piece of code that needs to be deployed in a tenant level. You can't really test that with only a site collection. But you can install the package for the site only and that will still work.

Same for any feature/functionality/provisioning that requires isolated tenant to be properly tested. Hence why they recommend a tenant. Otherwise you should be just fine with site collections.

Comment: Thanks Richado. I think we are gonna have both site level and tenant level, so I think we may have to take their suggestion, it would be expensive though, LOL. Thanks again.