# How to deal with UAT / Prod setup of spfx projects with only 1 environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Currently my organization only has 1 environment which are both used for uat and production. UAT only has a separate `subsite /uat/<subsite name>` where we deploy our projects for UAT. we have been asking the network team to provide us with a separate UAT environment but thats for a different problem.

Currently the setup is we have a different repository for UAT and another for PROD, i know it's not the best practice because this involved manually copying over the code to the prod repository and manually changing the solution id and component ids. even the CI/CD pipelines are different for the 2. this could impose issues  and nightmare scenarios where devs missed something to be copied over to the PROD repository then there might issues in production that does not exist in UAT.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: You can create **Site Collection Level App Catalog** site for UAT sites. please follow [this] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog) article to configure site collection level app catalog

Comment: Here is a similar issue with yours, please make a reference https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/295519/how-to-set-up-qa-and-uat-environment-in-sharepoint-onlinenot-on-prem-for-spfx